# Is there an Android N Emulator for Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

Is there an Android N Emulator for Eclipse? When attempting to create a new Android Virtual Device, I can select Android N - API Level 24 as the target but the CPU drop down indicates that there are "no system images installed for this target". Do I need to install this image myself and if so, how?

I'm running Eclipse (Kepler) SDK 4.3.2.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to install required OS image using Android SDK Manager.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much